# PHP Object Oriented Class With DateTime to Month and Day

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, debugging, blogs

How to convert the datetime  to a standard blog friendly date such as 'June 12, 2018 or 3 hours ago' once it's been picked up from the mysql database as a 
'Select * from photos'

I am using the same structure database as the example of selecting the date and converting it in the mysql query.

Is there a good way to convert is from the datetime value in php, or when using `select *` can I convert it before it reaches php?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC ";
$sql .= "LIMIT {$items_per_page} ";
$sql .= "OFFSET {$paginate->offset()}";

$photos = Photo::find_by_query($sql);
 <div class="small">Posted on: <time datetime="2018-05-29T17:00"><?php echo $photo->date_created; ?>
```

Comment: convert it to what? maybe you're trying to format the date not convert it?

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the datetime either in mysql or php. In your case, it would be fine to format using mysql DATE_FORMAT:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_created,'%d-%m-%Y %r') as datecreated FROM photos
```

this will give you date in this format:

> 2018-06-14 09:54:00 PM

Using DATE_FORMAT() function you can format the date and time the way you want. You can check the format options [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp):
For PHP have a look at [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: Also, you can try this build-in PHP function - `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $yourDateFetchedFromDB)`.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%M %e, %Y)

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with this as it's not prepared and could be optimized?

```
$sql = "SELECT *, (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_created,'%M %d, %Y')) as date_created FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC ";
$sql .= "LIMIT {$items_per_page} ";
$sql .= "OFFSET {$paginate->offset()}";
```

Comment: this is another topic. You should create a new question with this or search an answer in SO. I gave the answer to your question already. If it works for you, you can accept it by clicking the tick icon on my answer.